# Safari browser unresponsive img onerror function

Tags: javascript, image, safari, onerror

```
<img src="the wrong img url" onerror="this.src='the right img url'" alt="" class="hide-img">
```

in chrome, the img url will changed, but it's not changed in safari, my phone is XR, system is 14.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Try `onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='the right img url';"`